# Monitoring incoming SMS messages in Android

Tags: android, sms

I have this program that will try to monitor incoming SMS messages.  But when I tried to run my program in the emulator and I tried to send a SMS message, it works.  But when I installed my program in my phone, its not working.

What is the problem?

And I want to run the program at the backend as well. How to do that?

BTW, below are the whole codes for this sample app.

Thanks

RJ

---

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if(intent!=null && 
                intent.getAction()!=null && 
                ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())==0)
        {
            Object[]pduArray= (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];

            for (int i = 0; i<pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[])pduArray [i]); 
            }
            Log.d("MySMSMonitor","SMS Message Received.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="spy.Frandy.com"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TelephonyDemo"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MySMSMonitor"> <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.telephony.SmsManager; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TelephonyDemo extends Activity
{
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        Button sendBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendSmsBtn);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText addrTxt = (EditText)TelephonyDemo.this.findViewById(R.id.addrEditText);

            EditText msgTxt = (EditText)TelephonyDemo.this.findViewById(R.id.msgEditText);
            try { 
                sendSmsMessage(
                        addrTxt.getText().toString(),msgTxt.getText().toString()); 
                Toast.makeText(TelephonyDemo.this, "SMS Sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(TelephonyDemo.this, "Failed to send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void sendSmsMessage(String address,String message)throws Exception {
        SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
        smsMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: saying not working will not help, pin point the error. Is it a crash? or some functionality not working

Comment: it doesn't crush.. onReceive() is not being called

Comment: try to get a toast just after the line : public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { , before you put your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply insist you to use `ContentObserver` and register `content://sms` Uri and fetch the `type` of the SMS using

```
cusor.getString(cusor.getColumnIndex("type")); // 1 = SMS Received 
                                               // 2 =  SMS Sent
```

Further you can easily get the required data from the cursor that you fetched. [`Here`](http://katharnavas.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/listening-for-outgoing-sms-or-send-sms-in-android/) is a blog for the same.

Comment: although this answer would be ideal for monitoring sms (past/present/future), google has indirectly stated that querying the ContentProvider `content://sms` could potentially break on newer devices, since its not part of the SDK. Now obviously I doubt any manufacture or sms app would deviate from backwards compatibility but you never know. I would still worry about getting the broadcast receiver to work, at least for future projects. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1976557/1443717

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume with the little detail you have provided that the reason it works on a emulator and not your actual phone; may be another conflicting app intercepting the messages before they are broadcasted to your app.

try adding `android:priority="1000"` to your intent-filter of your receiver in your apps manifest
(a thousand being whatever number you feel necessary, could be higher if needed)

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

more info on - [intent-filter priority](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority)

Comment: what are you using to "send" and SMS to the phone? are you getting a notification of the SMS via the stock messaging app?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<receiver android:name=".MySMSMonitor"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">

      <intent-filter android:priority="2">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```